# Is spark-redis write dataframe an atomic operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, redis, spark-redis

When using spark-redis connector for writing a spark dataframe to redis, can we consider that as an atomic operation? Meaning, while the write job is running or if it fails, there is no partial data available in redis.